# Discount input not working on Shopify cart page

Tags: shopify, liquid

I need a coupon code input on my cart page but it doesn't seem to work in its plain form:

```
<input class="discount-code-field" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="discount" placeholder="Enter coupon code here" />
```

I have it right before the submit button, inside the form.

Live coupons are not being applied to the order on the checkout page.

Is there anything else I need to do for it to work?

**Edit:**
The form looks like this —

```
<form action="/cart" method="post" class="cart">

  ............

  <div class="bottom-box">
     <input class="discount-code-field" autocomplete="off" type="text" name="discount" placeholder="Enter coupon code here" />
     <input type="submit" value="Proceed to checkout" name="checkout" class="cart-submit w-button"/>
  </div>
</form>
```

And it redirects to a URL like this:
`https://store.com/4934605xxxx/checkouts/04d6478feeb9d3262fbea5571b682ebc?_ga=2.260083023.358228188.1608464294-110675315.1604953057`

Comment: As per Shopify documentation, you can applied the coupon codes over the Checkout page only, if you want to use and them over the cart page you need to use any 3rd party APP for it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As long as your cart is not using AJAX to update and redirect this should work.

The checkout page accepts a get argument of `?discount=` and adding a field with a `name="discount"` will add that argument to the checkout.

This works **only** if you submit the standard form directly. (if you update the cart, the field discount text will not be present and you need to re-enter it again) If you must update the form you will need to keep the discount code in some way, via updating the cart with ajax or storing it as a cookie.

So your code should be working, I double checked it on my dev store and there is no issues, it applies a discount to the checkout page since the get argument is present.

**PS:** This does not add a discount to the cart object, it only allows for the checkout redirect to include a get argument, nothing else. So this is equivalent to making a link with `<a href="/checkout?discount=YOUR_CODE">Checkout</a>`

Comment: What if I use a `post` form? e.g `<form action="{{ routes.cart_url }}" method="post" novalidate class="cart">`

Comment: @Ricardo the cart form is `POST` by default. It will set the discount as a query param nonetheless, it's not a default behavior but they do some "magic" there and it becomes a query param.

Comment: Any ideas on how to debug why it doesn't work?

Comment: @Ricardo are you expecting for the prices on the cart page to change? (since this wont happen) Please clarify what do you mean by not working? Are you redirected to the checkout page with the get argument present in the URL or not? If the get argument is not present there is high change that you are using JS to redirect to the checkout page instead of submitting the form normally.

Comment: Nope, I don't need it to update the numbers on the cart page. I just want it to be applied on checkout. I have updated my initial question with more code and details.

Comment: @Ricardo there is `?_ga=2.260083023.358228188.1608464294-110675315.1604953057` in your checkout url, so there is something modifying it. Please turn off your JS from the dev console debugger option and test if it's still not working.

Comment: Yeah, it works with JS disabled. Will be looking into what is causing this.